# PyQt5 applications take 5 seconds to load

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

It take 5 seconds to load even in the simplest apps like this:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QWidget()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Specifically on show() method. It started a week ago, and I don't know why; before that, the loading was instant

Using cProfile i get this:

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    5.063    5.063    5.063    5.063 {built-in method show}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

Also tried with 2 widgets
with show and qtimer.singleshot:

```
1    5.057    5.057    5.057    5.057 {built-in method show} 
1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {singleShot}
```

with 2 show methods:

```
2 5.063 2.532 5.063 2.532 {built-in method show}
```

so no matter how many widgets are there, it will always take 5 seconds to load

I'm on Windows 11. python version is 3.10.11, pyqt5 version is 5.15.10. I reinstalled pyqt5, ran it in the venv, still doesn't work. same story in pyqt6. Also tried to run it from vscode and cmd

Comment: cannot reproduce. The code you posted opens a window instantly on my computer

Comment: yep, that's the problem. it shouldn't take this much time. i didn't change or update anything, it just start to load slower at a random moment

Comment: Are you running it from a command prompt or within an IDE? If so, which one? Does the same happens when trying to show *another* window after a certain timeout (or even toggling visibility of the same) using QTimer? For instance: `other = QWidget()` `QTimer.singleShot(1000, other.show)`

Comment: i run it from vscode, but also tried cmd.
with singleshot:
        `1    5.057    5.057    5.057    5.057 {built-in method show}`
        `1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {singleShot}`
with second show()
       ` 2    5.063    2.532    5.063    2.532 {built-in method show}`
can't format this better sry
this is strange... so doesn't matter how many show methods i use, sum will be 5 seconds ig(tried with 3, 1.699 for each)

Comment: @glikoliz Please don't use comments to add information that is fundamental in the question, instead take your time and properly [edit] your post after thorough testing while providing accurate results within their context of usage. Also, use `@username` whenever more than two users (the author and the first commenter) join the conversation, otherwise we'll not get any notification of further comments (and we cannot follow all posts).

Answer (score 0):

Ok i just reinstalled windows, now it works normally